# How to open a csv file for reading purpose using mmap in python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to open csv file for reading purpose. But I'm facing some exceptions regarding to that.

I'm using Python 2.7.

**main.python-**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

   f = open('input.csv','r+b')
   m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
   reader = csv.DictReader(iter(m.readline, ""))

for read in reader:
    num = read['time']
    print num
```

**output-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/PycharmProjects/time_gap_Task/main.py", line 22, in <module>
for read in reader:
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/csv.py", line 109, in __next__
   self.fieldnames
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/csv.py", line 96, in fieldnames
   self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

How to resolve this error? and how to open csv file using mmap and csv in good manner so code is working perfect?

Comment: You're using python 2.7 and your lib directory is named python 3.4?

Comment: Why do you need mmap instead of normal file buffering?

Comment: my file is very large so I'm using mmap.

Comment: Python's csv readers read from a file a line at a time, so that's not a problem. You don't need mmap for this.

Comment: If I want to use mmap for csv file reading then how to implement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you asked this a while ago, but I actually created a module for myself that does this, because I do a lot of work with large CSV files, and sometimes I need to convert them into dictionaries, based on a key.  Below is the code I've been using.  Please feel free to modify as needed.

```
def MmapCsvFileIntoDict(csvFilePath, skipHeader = True, transform = lambda row: row, keySelector = lambda o: o):
    """
    Takes a CSV file path and uses mmap to open the file and return a dictionary of the contents keyed
    on the results of the keySelector.  The default key is the transformed object itself.  Mmap is used because it is
    a more efficient way to process large files.

    The transform method is used to convert the line (converted into a list) into something else.  Hence 'transform'.
    If you don't pass it in, the transform returns the list itself.
    """
    contents = {}
    firstline = False

    try:
        with open(csvFilePath, "r+b") as f:
            # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
            mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
            for line in iter(mm.readline, b''):
                if firstline == False:
                    firstline = True

                    if skipHeader == True:
                        continue

                row = ''

                line = line.decode('utf-8')
                line = line.strip()

                row = next(csv.reader([line]), '')

                if transform != None and callable(transform):
                    if row == None or row == '':
                        continue

                    value = transform(row)
                else:
                    value = row

                if callable(keySelector):    
                    key = keySelector(value)
                else:
                    key = keySelector

                contents[key] = value

    except IOError as ie:
        PrintWithTs('Error decomposing the companies: {0}'.format(ie))
        return {}
    except:
        raise

    return contents
```

When you call this method, you have some options.

Assume you have a file that looks like:

```
Id, Name, PhoneNumber 
1, Joe, 7175551212 
2, Mary, 4125551212 
3, Vince, 2155551212 
4, Jane, 8145551212
```

The easiest way to call it is like this:

```
dict = MmapCsvFileIntoDict('/path/to/file.csv', keySelector = lambda row: row[0])
```

What you get back is a dict looking like this:

```
{ '1' : ['1', 'Joe', '7175551212'], '2' : ['2', 'Mary', '4125551212'] ...
```

One thing I like to do is create a class or a namedtuple to represent my data:

```
class CsvData:
    def __init__(self, row):
        self.Id = int(row[0])
        self.Name = row[1].upper()
        self.Phone = int(row[2])
```

And then when I call the method, I pass in a second lambda to transform each row in the file to an object I can work with:

```
dict = MmapCsvFileIntoDict('/path/to/file.csv', transform = lambda row: CsvData(row), keySelector = lambda o: o.Id)
```

What I get back that time looks like:

```
{ 1 : <object instance>, 2 : <object instance>...
```

I hope this helps!  Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

When open a file with the flag `b` like this:

```
f = open('input.csv','r+b')
```

**You read the file as bytes** and not as string.

So, try to change the flags to `r`:

```
f = open('input.csv','r')
```

Answer (score -2):

if you just want to read data with specific columnes from csv file, just try:

```
import csv
with open('input.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print row['time']
```

Comment: @LFJ- I want to use mmap

Comment: why you need mmap?

Comment: my file is very large so I'm using mmap.

Comment: @FujiaoLiu mmap is used to process large files as they are read where either the entire file can't be stored into memory (big data) or where the process does not have access to a lot of memory, this solution would not work.

Comment: @Rohit I disagree. Memory mapping is another way to perform file I/O in memory. Depending on how you open the file, and the value in the length parameter, you are going to read the whole file or a portion. As the name suggests, mmap read things  into memory, but because it is much lower-level than the traditional read operation, it can result in better performance and memory efficiency.

Comment: @AndreaMoro where exactly do you disagree, what you're saying is orthogonal to my comment

Comment: @Rohit you say that files CAN'T be read in memory. That is what confuses me. Might be out was a typo, or that I didn't pick the specific correctly, but to my understanding is the opposite.